# Yellow screen of death when changing login on Data Explorer

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer, user-accounts

I've just tried to change the *Login* field on Data Explorer to **Ben** and it's given me the yellow screen of death when I try. It did however allow me to change it from what it was to **BenP**, so it's not totally broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that login names must be unique.

The system now shows you an error message if you try to change your login name to a name that already exists in the system.

Comment: My intention was for logins to be unique, the correct behavior here is to say "that login is taken, try something else"

Comment: @waffles: Okay. For completeness, clearing the login field completely and submitting also causes a crash.

Comment: Thanks to the NerdDinner walkthrough, I believe I have this fixed! I will test my changes tomorrow and go from there. @waffles

Comment: This fix is now live.